# For loop in c defined with &&

Tags: c

This is just an example, but what actually does logical and (&&) operator in this loop (or any other loop).
And what means (&&) in this line "equal=equal&&(first->number==end->number)", knowing that equal is an int that is used like boolean - it stores 0 or 1.

```
    for(i=1; i<=n/2 && equal; i++){
        equal=equal&&(first->number==end->number);
        first=first->next;
        end=end->previous;
    }
```

Comment: This is one of the basic features in C. You should read about operators in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop will continue only if both `i<=n/2` AND `equal` are true (`equal` is considered true if != 0).

```
equal=equal&&(first->number==end->number);
```

This line means that `equal` will be true only if it was already true and the condition `first->number==end->number` is also true.

So, your code is moving the beginning of the list forward, and the end backward, and it will stop only if you reach the half of the list (`n/2`) or the first and last values are different.